# How do I prove something is a basis? (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For $c = \langle 1,1+x,1+x+x^2,1+x+x^2+x^3\rangle$ I am asked whether this sequence is a basis for polynomials of degree $3$.

Would it be sufficient to show that it is a basis by:

Linear independence: Converting it to a $4\times 4$ matrix and demonstrating that it reduces to a diagonal form.

Generate the space: Demonstrating how its contents can be linearly combined to form the standard basis vectors which span polynomials of degree $3$?

Comment: Yes. But It is simpler to calculate the determinant and use that: $card(\{1;1 + x; 1 + x + x ^2;1 + x + x^2 + x^3 \}) = 4 = \dim (P_4(\mathbb{R}))$ (assuming a real polynomial space).

Comment: In general, any set of polynomials $\{p_i | 0 \leq i \leq n\}$ with $\deg p_i = i$ will span the set of polynomials of degree $\leq n$, because if you write out the change of basis matrix in terms of the basis $\{x^i | 0 \leq i \leq n\}$ it will be triangular with non-zero entries on the diagonal and so the determinant is nonzero.

Comment: Note though that the set of polynomials of degree exactly $3$ is not a vector space. e.g., $x^3 - x^3 = 0$ is not in the space as it does not have degree $3$.

Comment: @JairTaylor I think he just got confused, cause $1$, $1+x$ and $1+x+x^2$ are in the set but not degree $3$.

Comment: The easiest way to prove linear independence is by the definition: "Suppose $a,b,c,d$ are scalars that satisfy $$a(1) + b(1+x) + c(1+x+x^2) + d(1+x+x^2+x^3)=0 \quad \forall x$$  Show that $a=b=c=d=0$."

Comment: It is well-known that  a triangular system is a basis.

Answer (score 2):

Since $$x^3 = (x^3+x^2+x+1)-(x^2+x+1)$$
$$x^2 = (x^2+x+1)-(x+1)$$
$$x = (x+1)-1$$

$$ 1= 1$$

we see that dose vectors spans the space of all polynomials of degree 3 or less. Since it dimension is 4 it is a basis of that space.